# use ringbuf and perfbuf depending on kernel version dynamically

Tags: ebpf, bcc, bcc-bpf, libbpf

We are trying to support older kernel version with perf_buff vs. also newer kernel version with ring_buff. With some kernel guarding, we could try to compile time. We wanted to have BPF_CORE feature to avoid different kernel version maintenance issues.

Is it possible to detect kernel version in bpf program at runtime and use respective data structure.

In user space we could use uname(x) to detect kernel version, anything in bpf kernel program to detect kernel version.

similarly, support for diff kernel version bpf_program__attach_uprobe  vs. bpf_program__attach_uprobe_multi and kprobe versions.

Question is similar to [ebpf - use ringbuf and perfbuf depending on kernel version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74976615/ebpf-use-ringbuf-and-perfbuf-depending-on-kernel-version) (this is compile time fix).
Looks like bpf provides macro
https://nakryiko.com/posts/bpf-core-reference-guide.
extern int LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION __kconfig;

Detect using uname in bpf userspace set it in global variable , share with kernel bpf. ?

Is there better way to solve issue.

```
      // user space bpf 
     kernel_version = uname(buff);
     if (kernel_version < 5.8) {
         load_per_buffer();
     } else {
        load_ring_buffer(); 
    }

   // kernel space bpf
     kernel_version = bpf_kernel_version() //extern int LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION __kconfig;
     if (kernel_version < 5.8) {
        update_per_buffer(); and submit;
     } else {
        update_ring_buffer();  and submit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the only way to get the kernel version is to use `extern int LINUX_KERNEL_VERSION __kconfig;` which you mentioned, and it should do the job.

Is there a specific reason you don't want to use it?